# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid - PG::CharacterNotInRepertoire: ERROR: invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg

The existing solutions for this question not helps.

Rails: `5.2`
ruby : `2.4.1`
pg: `0.18`

```
This is the query from the rails log: 
INSERT INTO "users" ("first_name") VALUES ('\xC3\r\x04\t\x03\x02qlF\xA4\.....')
```

`first_name` value is encrypted using `active_record-pgcrypto`  gem

`first_name` is `string` datatype in `users` table

copy paste the query in pgAdmin works well. But the application throw the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the [pgcrypto install documentation](https://github.com/Plinq/pgcrypto#tldr-install) encrypted data should use a `:binary` column. Otherwise Rails and Postgres will interpret it as UTF-8 characters, and some combinations of bytes are not valid UTF-8 characters.